# Snippet choices: display one value and complete with another value

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, google-font-api, vscode-snippets

I don't know if it's possible, but I want to check with all the awesome people who read and answer these questions.

I have this snippet I'm making for css/scss/sass to help with import font statements. This is the code I currently have and would like to build on:

```
"Import font": {
    "scope": "css,scss,sass",
    "prefix": "@import, @im, @i",
    "body": "@import url('${1|https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=,https://|}');"
},
```

This works just fine. It allows me to choose between the google fonts url or just a blank `https://`.

My question is, is it possible to have the choices show a different value when tabbing into the snippet. For example, have the first option show `Google Fonts` and the other choice to show `Other` (or something along those lines).

My end goal for this would be to have this snippet allow me to choose from a list of fonts I often use, but I want to make it readable.

EDIT:
@Mark's answer allowed me to continue with my POC and I'd like to share that with you all:

```
"Import font": {
    // "scope": "css,scss,sass",
    "prefix": "@import, @im, @i",
    // "body": "@import url('${1|https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=,https://|}');"
    "body": "@import ${1|url('Google Fonts,url('Other|}');" // explained below**
},
"Google Fonts": {
    // "scope": "css,scss,sass",  // just disabled for testing purposes
    "prefix": "url('Google Fonts",
    "body": "url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${1|Open Sans,Other Font|}"
},
"Open Sans": {
    // "scope": "css,scss,sass",
    "prefix": "Open Sans",
    "body": "Open+Sans&display=swap"
},
```

Obviously, there are holes in this concept when it comes to choosing styles, weights, etc., but the idea is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and the workflow isn't too bad.  You need the following snippets:

```
 "Import font": {
      // "scope": "css,scss,sass",
      "prefix": "@import, @im, @i",

      // "body": "@import url('${1|https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=,https://|}');"

      "body": "@import ${1|url('Google Fonts,url('Other|}');"  // explained below**
  },


  "Google Fonts": {
      // "scope": "css,scss,sass",  // just disabled for testing purposes
      "prefix": "url('Google Fonts",
      "body": "url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family="
  },

  "Other": {
      // "scope": "css,scss,sass",
      "prefix": "url('Other",
      "body": "url('https://"
  },
```

**RELOAD WINDOW vscode** after making these changes. Important!

---

`"body": "@import ${1|url('Google Fonts,url('Other|}');"`

This is written like this because triggering the completion snippets (Google Fonts and Other) **need a space preceding** their prefixes otherwise vscode will not recognize them as snippets.  Since their will be a space (prior to `url....` it will look like another snippet and can be completed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

The demo gif isn't great on including the keystrokes but you do one extra <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> after selecting your option to trigger the completion snippet.

Demo:

[image: font snippet choices]

Comment: This would be easier to do if one could do transforms directly on snippet choices/placeholders but that isn't supported :>{

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you! This is great!