# Snippets: nested placeholders not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, nested, placeholder, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to get nested placeholders to work in snippets, which *should* work [according to the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholders). But when using it it's basically treated as a single tab stop.

Test snippet

```
{
    "nestedPlaceholders": {
        "prefix": "nestedPlaceholders",
        "body": ["<test ${1:first placeholder ${2:Second placeholder}} />"],
        "description": "Test for nested placeholders"
    }
}
```

[Result video](https://reddit-uploaded-video.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/t2_n3sfs%2Fmlesogwej5z41)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that is expected behaviour.  Here is what is happening.  In this form:

```
${1:first placeholder ${2:Second placeholder}}
```

The `${2:Second placeholder}` is part of the first placeholder!  So it all should appear selected on the first tabstop and when you type over that first placeholder default text, you also delete the second tabstop/placeholder.  It works much better if the order is:

```
${2:second placeholder ${1:first placeholder}}
```

Now accepting or typing over the first placeholder does not delete the second placeholder.  But the first placeholder default text (`first placeholder` in my example) is still part of the second placeholder text and so will be eliminated if you type over it.  It will remain if you accept the second placeholder text with a <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Obviously, if you want the two placeholders to operate independently, don't nest them:

```
"<test ${1:first placeholder} ${2:Second placeholder} />",
```

So I think the nested placeholder example in the docs is probably not helpful in very many situations because if you want the second placeholder default text but not the first - you lose the second text so what's the point.  But I do think it is actually operating as it should - it just isn't very helpful in that form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that the example I provided is somewhat useless in the real world, though I still think there has to be some functionality given the extra mention in the docs.

I guess what I was hoping for is more in the lines of tab stops within options:

`${1|option1 attr1=${2:Option 1 Placeholder 1} attr2=${3:Option 1 Placeholder 2},option2 attr3=${2:Option 2 Placeholder 1} attr4=${3:Option 2 Placeholder 2}|}`

This would give different content based on the selected option, but with functioning tab stops and placeholders.

Comment: That is a very different question.  The grammar does not allow anything but plain text in a `choice` option.  But there is a way to do it by a trick.  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083405/snippet-choices-display-one-value-and-complete-with-another-value/61086559#61086559.  It looks like a different question but the same technique can be used to accomplish what you want.  Since you are now asking something different I suggest asking another question where you can format your code more clearly.